# How to get started with twitCurl?

Tags: c++, twitter

I am trying to use twitCurl and I am following instructions given on

[1]: http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/wiki/WikiHowToUseTwitcurlLibrary under the Unix/Linux section.

Getting stuck while doing

```
g++ twitterClient.cpp -ltwitcurl
```

It gives an error message

```
  In file included from twitterClient.h:4:0,
                     from twitterClient.cpp:1:
    includes/twitcurl.h:8:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

The file curl.h is inside curl/ but it still gives an error.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

Add `-I<path to curl/curl.h>` to your building command.